# How to install Deluge Client and Web UI

Tags: raspbian, networking, deluge

how do i install deluge client w/ web ui in Rpi *(not the headless server type since it's all i can see when i google)* my os is the raspbian wheezy, still a noob here :)

Comment: Not sure to understand your question. Do you want to display from your RPi a web UI provided by a deluge server? Or you want a BT server on your RPi that provides a web UI, and then display the web UI from another computer?

Comment: somewhat of the latter question

Comment: It seems like what psyko really needs is a file server, so he can retrieve his downloaded files. I use samba for this as it allows me to connect from Windows 7 via the Windows file manager. The pie makes a great low power seedbox and file server in this manner.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply install deluge from the terminal using the package manager;

```
sudo apt-get install deluge
```

You then need to start the daemon;

```
sudo service deluged start
```

Then to interact with the daemon using the web ui you must start that;

```
sudo service deluge-web start
```

Then browse to `https://localhost:8112`. The password should be `deluge`.

Comment: im sorry for the question being not understandable anyways u may have answered my question, another question though, how do i transfer the settings and torrents to my local deluge(my pc), for short id like to see my torrents in my pc while my RPi downloads

Comment: by the way excellent answer very simple and understandable

Comment: You can use any client to view that deluge daemon. Browse to the `https://address:8112` where `address` is the IP address of the Pi on the network.

Comment: what i mean is not from the browser but the local application form of Deluge. i.e. "C:/Apps/Deluge/Deluge.exe"

Comment: Not as far as I know. You can do that with Transmission though (a different torrent client). What's wrong with using the browser?

Comment: i'd prefer the local one, it's much more responsive than the browser client.

Comment: This solution does not seem to be working as of today. [See here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28338/what-is-the-current-working-method-of-installing-deluge-with-webui-on-a-raspberr).

Answer (score 4):

@psyko666 if you are still looking for an answer, the following guide shows how to connect to a deluge-daemon running on your RPI from a Deluge client on another machine.

http://www.howtogeek.com/142044/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-an-always-on-bittorrent-box/

Answer (score 0):

short answer: if you have deluge client runiing on your pc .. turn off classic mode , if deluge is running properly on your pi , you will see it as an option , u=you can then conect it up that way .. you might have to turn on the option for allow remote conetion for the deaom though the web up first