# What is the current working method of installing deluge with WebUI on a Raspberry Pi2?

Tags: raspbian, deluge, web-interface

I was trying to follow [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/4317).

The first command, `sudo apt-get install deluge` works properly. After the `deluge` package is installed, however, I cannot progress further:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo service deluged start
deluged: unrecognized service
```

In case it matters, my Rpi2 is updated to the latest firmware+raspbian as of today.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 3.18.8-v7+ #764 SMP PREEMPT Tue Mar 3 15:22:38 GMT 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo rpi-update
 *** Raspberry Pi firmware updater by Hexxeh, enhanced by AndrewS and Dom
 *** Performing self-update
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  8107  100  8107    0     0  21092      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 27574
 *** Relaunching after update
 *** Raspberry Pi firmware updater by Hexxeh, enhanced by AndrewS and Dom
 *** Your firmware is already up to date
```

To clarify, I also want the deluge and its WebUI to run as a daemon.

Edit 1: I tried installing the package called `deluged`, which was actually installed, but the service still doesn't start.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7120/deluge-have-no-init-scripts)?

Comment: Yeah.  "Unrecognized service" == No init scripts.